# Date Picker with multiple dates selection

Tags: xml, calendar, nativescript, telerik-appbuilder, nativescript-telerik-ui

I am working on Nativescript application where i have need for **From date** to **To date** (Range of date). I tried to implement [RadCalendar](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/Calendar/overview) but i could not find method or attribute for multiple dates selection OR dates range selection.

Below is my **XML** code for calander view

```
<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" 
  xmlns:calendar="nativescript-telerik-ui-pro/calendar"
  showingModally="onLoaded">
    <StackLayout id="calendarModal" width="90%" height="65%" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" backgroundColor="white" opacity="1">
        <StackLayout class="popup-wrapper">
            <calendar:RadCalendar id="calendar" dateSelected="onDateSelected" />
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used `selectionMode` attribute. [Reference](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/api/classes/radcalendar.html#selectionmode)

Other available options are

1. Multiple
2. None
3. Range
4. Single

**XML**

```
<calendar:RadCalendar id="calendar" dateSelected="onDateSelected" selectionMode="Range" />
```